# Android SDK installed but not seen by cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I've installed `android studio 3` which sees `android-sdk`:
[image: Screen from Adnroid Studio]

The same path I have in enviroments variables but I cannot use android sdk with cordova. (I'm makeing ionic app).
Here is screen shot from IDE:

[image: from PHPStorm]

Edit:
More screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What cordova is looking for at this step is not the sdk but the sdk tools. Have you installed the sdk tooks (middle tab in your first picture)?

To know what exactly is missing you can use the command

`cordova requirements android --verbose`

It will show you that cordova is trying to launch the command `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin\avdmanager.bat list target` and displays that the SDK is not found if the command is not found.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've added more screenshots

Comment: the output of requirements says that it finds the sdk tools but not the tatget sdk. I think the versions of android sdk you installed dont match with the version of cordova android platform you have.